# How to access Jenkins using basic authentication

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to access Jenkins using basic authentication. I have started the Jenkins as mentioned in [Quick and Simple Security page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security) with user name "user" and password as "password" and choosing Delegate to servlet container for security realm and Legacy mode for authorization strategy. 
But when I try to access job configuration of a job(my_test_job) using curl command as:

> `curl -X GET --user user:password --insecure https:///localhost:9000/job/my_test_job/config.xml`

(using same credentials that which used in the server start up as in [1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security)), it wan't authorized and I can see following log in the Kenkins:

> While serving `https://localhost:9000/job/my_test_job/config.xml`: 
>   hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Job/ExtendedRead permission.

What am I missing here? How can I configure jenkins to access using simple basic authentication? Appreciate your help..

Note: I have enabled https and and changed the port to 9000 and my jenkins version is 1.609

Comment: Using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi/0.2.26 is not a option ?

Comment: Hi @alkuzad
Nope. I just want to configure jenkins, such that it can access using basic authentication as in curl command given above.

Comment: Oh, ok. So be sure to use cookies with curl to be authenticated, --cookie-jar option. I also do not know if Jenkins supports such authorization - it's intended rather for FTP where the site displays popup window for logging - not for custom logins like Jenkins have.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients also indicates using api-key, maybe this would be better approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has its own authentication mechanism therefore you can't access it by using Apache basic authentication by default (it's a java app, not Apache website). Although you can delegate the authentication to the reverse proxy that you run in front of Jenkins. Here are the steps:

1. Consider installing [Reverse Proxy Auth](https://plugins.jenkins.io/reverse-proxy-auth-plugin) to delegate the authentication to the reverse proxy.
2. Configure [Apache](https://plugins.jenkins.io/reverse-proxy-auth-plugin) or [nginx](https://serverfault.com/q/233951/130437) to use Apache basic authentication. See: [Apache frontend for security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Apache+frontend+for+security) and [Secure Jenkins with Apache basic authentication](https://coderwall.com/p/ecl6ua/secure-jenkins-with-apache-basic-authentication).
3. Restrict your direct access to Jenkins by listening only on local IP address.

   On Linux this can be configured in JAVA_ARGS in `/etc/default/jenkins` file, but it may vary depending on your Linux distribution or operating system. See: [How can I get Jenkins to stop listening for remote connections?](https://serverfault.com/q/233951/130437)
4. Now access your Jenkins via reverse proxy port.